# Gamil logged me in when i give my email address without dot or with dot?

Tags: gmail

i don't know whether to ask this question in stack overflow is appropriate or not. I am sorry if the question not fulfilling the rules.

My Google mail account is shakil.cph@gmail.com

My question is that before login when i am entering the mail 
          address without the dot mean like this shakilcph@gmail.com it also
           logged me in to shakil.cph@gmail.com. What is the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?hl=en

> Gmail doesn't recognize dots as characters within usernames, you can add or remove the dots from a Gmail address without changing the actual destination address; they'll all go to your inbox, and only yours.
>
> ...
>
> You can see this if you try to sign in with your username, but adding or removing a dot from it. You'll still go to your account.

A note for anyone using Google Apps:

> One last thing: Google Apps **does** recognize dots. If you'd like to have a dot in your username, please ask your domain administrator to add your preferred username as a nickname.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  It mean that abc.c@gmail.com and abcc@gmail.com are same .

Comment: @Mohit Yes, and my answer clearly states that Google considers them to be the same thing. They ignore the dots.